# How to update read books in goodreads as per the updated date?

Tags: javascript, browser, web-console

I am trying to use java script to update the goodreads data using the webconsole in firefox (Inspect element). I forgot to update the read date when I added the rating for some books. It's very tedious to update the date by hand. I agree that this is a problem with goodreads (or my usage of it).

Does anyone know how to update this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your browser console. This should do the trick.

```
var books = document.getElementById("books")

for (var j = 1; j<= books.rows.length; j++) {
   var id = books.rows[j].cells[2].getElementsByClassName("tooltipTrigger")[0].getAttribute("data-resource-id");
   var date_added = books.rows[j].cells[23].innerText;
   books.rows[j].cells[22].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click();
   reviewEditor.afterSummon(this, id, "read_at", {value: date_added, reading_session_id: "new"} );
   reviewEditor.save();
}
```